# neo4j-import import error: Collision in source with too many lines

Tags: neo4j

I want to import data in csv file into neo4j with the following command:

```
../bin/neo4j-import --into ../data/databases/entity.db --nodes:Entity
"nodes_header.csv,node.csv" --relationships:RELE 
"edges_header.csv,edge.csv" --multiline-fields=true --bad-tolerance 
100000000 --stacktrace true --skip-duplicate-nodes true
```

there are about 2 billion nodes and 10 billion edges in the CSV file.

nodes_header.csv 's content is:
type, value, id:ID

edges_header.csv 's content is:
:START_ID, :END_ID

But i get the error like:

```
[*RESOLVE (82 collisions):61.19 GB------------------------------------------------------------]2.01B
[*RESOLVE (82 collisions):61.19 GB------------------------------------------------------------]2.03B
[*RESOLVE (82 collisions):61.19 GB------------------------------------------------------------]2.04B
[*RESOLVE (82 collisions):61.19 GB------------------------------------------------------------]2.06B
[*RESOLVE (82 collisions):61.19 GB------------------------------------------------------------]2.08B
[*RESOLVE (82 collisions):61.19 GB------------------------------------------------------------]2.09B
[*RESOLVE (82 collisions):61.19 GB------------------------------------------------------------]2.11B
[*RESOLVE (82 collisions):61.19 GB------------------------------------------------------------]2.13B
[*RESOLVE (82 collisions):61.19 GB------------------------------------------------------------]2.14BException in thread "Thread-1302" java.lan
g.IllegalArgumentException: Collision in source with too many lines (-2143568315)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.SourceInformation.encodeSourceInformation(SourceInformation.java:52)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.buildCollisionInfo(EncodingIdMapper.java:486)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.prepare(EncodingIdMapper.java:282)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.IdMapperPreparationStep.process(IdMapperPreparationStep.java:54)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.LonelyProcessingStep$1.run(LonelyProcessingStep.java:56)
Import error: Collision in source with too many lines (-2143568315)
Caused by:Collision in source with too many lines (-2143568315)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Collision in source with too many lines (-2143568315)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.SourceInformation.encodeSourceInformation(SourceInformation.java:52)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.buildCollisionInfo(EncodingIdMapper.java:486)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.prepare(EncodingIdMapper.java:282)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.IdMapperPreparationStep.process(IdMapperPreparationStep.java:54)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.LonelyProcessingStep$1.run(LonelyProcessingStep.java:56)

Input error: Collision in source with too many lines (-2143568315)
Caused by:Collision in source with too many lines (-2143568315)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Collision in source with too many lines (-2143568315)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.SourceInformation.encodeSourceInformation(SourceInformation.java:52)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.buildCollisionInfo(EncodingIdMapper.java:486)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.prepare(EncodingIdMapper.java:282)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.IdMapperPreparationStep.process(IdMapperPreparationStep.java:54)
at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.LonelyProcessingStep$1.run(LonelyProcessingStep.java:56)
```

Neo4j version: 3.1.2 community

Operating system: linux

is my usage of neo4j-import right?